# How to preserve recently cut tree stump?

Tags: protection, rot, tree

We're in the middle of major construction around our house, and to make room for a crane we had to take down a healthy 50-year old pine tree. We asked the arborist to leave a 3 foot high stump, and we're planning on mounting a sundial on it. What do we need to do to keep the stump from rotting out?

[image: the stump]

Comment: what are your plans for when this stump starts growing branches?

Comment: let it re-grow if it sprouts

Comment: Pine doesn't tend to regrow (@Jasen)

Comment: This isn't a home improvement question. Maybe try Gardening.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's going to rot. The only thing you can do is slow the rotting.

The bark is a problem because it retains moisture and insects live in the bark and outer inch of the wood. Removing the bark would help it last longer, but you certainly lose an aesthetic part of it. Also, ground contact is not ideal, but it could still last many years.

My advice is to coat the top with a clear water seal to prevent rain and snow melt from getting to it; this will likely need to be applied every couple of years. Leave the bark on until it starts peeling away on its own. If you don't have little kids or pets, spray it with an insecticide annually.

Comment: Agreed, except that normal polyurethane will soon crack and peel due to movement caused by moisture changes. I recommend an exterior spar varnish instead of regular poly, or some other clear wood preservative that does not create a hard surface coating.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it perhaps some kind of thick epoxy coating?

Comment: @Huesmann, I worry that anything that cures into a hard surface coating will crack as the stump dries out and shrinks. I was thinking more of a CWF or Thompsons Water Seal type product that soaks in and doesn't really leave a surface finish. Drawback is need for annual reapplication. Maybe thinking too much.... the stump is imperfect so maybe the suface treatment doesn't need to be... perfect.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it maybe the solution is to cut the exposed stump off, remove the rest of the stump, and put down a concrete (or even just gravel) base.  Then put the stump stub on top of the base.  If it rots, it's easy enough to replace it with a new stub—people have trees cut down all the time and offer the remains for firewood.

Comment: Jimmy is correct, epoxy will crack quite badly as the stump dries. I have some evidence for that experiment and it started off great, but after two years it went badly. And correct on the poly as well; amended to be a water sealant

Comment: One could argue that it's better to let the wood unsealed so it can dry. It _will_ wick moisture from the ground, so sealing the top is like putting an umbrella under a boat.

Answer (score 2):

Cut it off at the ground right now. If it stays planted it's a goner.

Then build a small paver platform and stand the stump on it with an air gap underneath. It'll dry out and last a few years. To extend that further, put a transparent roof over your sundial.